# Hodge star operator and exterior calculation

Tags: complex-geometry, exterior-algebra

I am learning complex geometry by D. Huybrechts. Here is a formula that I can't understand $$\omega \wedge \beta\wedge \star \alpha=\beta\wedge(\omega \wedge \star \alpha)\tag 1$$

Here $\omega$ is the fundamental form which is a $2$-form actually. And I try to expand both sides by the definition $\alpha \wedge \star \beta= \langle \alpha, \beta \rangle \cdot vol$

For LHS, we have $\langle \omega \wedge \beta,\alpha \rangle \cdot vol$  and for RHS, we have $\beta \wedge \langle \omega, \alpha \rangle \cdot vol$ But here is the things I don't understand:

(1)  And let's suppose $\alpha,\beta \in \land^k V^{*}$. For $\langle \omega \wedge \beta,\alpha \rangle$, here $\omega \wedge \beta$ is a $(k+2)$- form so how can an inner product operated by a $k+2$-form and a $k$-form ? So does for RHS.

(2) How to prove $(1)$ by expanding in my way or the other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\omega$ is a $2$-form, it commutes for the $\wedge$-product with other $p$-forms, (because if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $p$ and $q$-forms, $\alpha\wedge \beta = (-1)^{pq} \beta\wedge \alpha$). Moreover, this product is associative. Forget about the $\star$ in $(\star \alpha)$ and consider only $(\star\alpha)$ as a differential form. Then :
\begin{align}
\omega \wedge \beta \wedge \star \alpha &= \left(\omega \wedge \beta\right) \wedge \star \alpha \\
&= \left(\beta \wedge \omega \right)\wedge \star \alpha \\
&= \beta \wedge \left( \omega \wedge \star \alpha\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Oh, how careless I am ,I forgot $\omega$ is a two form. ..But I wonder can a p-form and a q-form operated on inner product? I learned that the inner pruduct is only defined for the same degree.

Comment: Let $n$ be the dimension of your vector space / manifold. If $\alpha$ is a $k$- form, then $\star \alpha$ is a $(n-k)$ -form. It is defined to be the unique for for which, for all $k$-forms $\theta$, $\theta \wedge \star \alpha = <\theta,\alpha> \mathrm{dvol}$. Here $\theta$ and $\alpha$ do have the same degree ! It is just the way to define the $(n-k)$-form $\star \alpha$. In your example, if $\omega$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are of degree $2$, $p$ and $q$ respectively and if $n$ is the dimension of the vector space, then $\omega\wedge \beta \wedge \star\alpha$ is of degree $2 + q + (n-p)$

Comment: I think I find what am I missing. The operation priority of Hodge $\star$ operator is less than the wedge operation !

Comment: It has to be read as $\omega \wedge \beta \wedge (\star \alpha)$. I don't get what priority you are talking about!

Comment: I originally believe we first do the wedge operation $(\omega \wedge \beta)  $ ,and form a $(p+2)$- form and then we apply the Hodge star operator, so $(\star \alpha)$ is actually $n-(p+2)$-form. so that the inner product have the same degree and it makes sense.That's what I originally mean by the "operation priority"... I made some mistskes.